Zebra printer print special charcter
Hy all. I have a Zebra printer. I want to print a DMC code with some special characters.
These characters are:
$1E
$1D

The complete DMC code is:
[)>$1E06$1D1P4533004683$1DS001266$1D7D0724$1DP00002735777$1E$04
I can't change the code because it is the standard code, and read out a lot of machines.
I try a lot of methods, but only the first three characters printed out ('[)>') the others not.
The last try command to the printer is this:
^XA
^XFE:LABEL.ZPL
^CC@
@FS
@FN1
@FD
[)>$1E06$1D1P4533004683$1DS001266$1D7D0724$1DP00002735777$1E$04
@FS
@CC^
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ

Anyone has an idea about the solution?

Try this:
^XA
^XFE:LABEL.ZPL
^CC@
@FS
@FN1
@FH$
@FD
[)>$1E06$1D1P4533004683$1DS001266$1D7D0724$1DP00002735777$1E$04
@FS
@CC^
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ


Note the added @FH$ before @FD!

FH defines the escape character for hex values (the following two characters after the escape character) for the following text of the FD command. Based on your example the $ character is used for this.
Be aware, in your example string $04 is at the end, which will also be interpreted as a hex value. But in your question you were only mentioning $1E and $1D!

Thank you for your help. I tried this, and it was working fine.
